# How to use layout and layout(land) xml files correctly?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an editText and some buttons within an activity. Every time I tilted the phone to landscape mode I reset it to the standard value. To change this, I added this line to the activity manifest:

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

And with this I got the same values in it changing phone orientation. But my layout was perfect in portrait mode and awful in landscape mode(buttons were off screen). So I got two xml files: layout and layout(land). In this way, if the phone is tilted when this activity is called, layout(land) is called. Otherwise, the portrait layout is called. But every time I tilt my phone after the activity was called the layout used keeps the same. I would like to know how to dynamically change layout during activity call and after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are preventing the activity from reloading by specifying `android:configChanges` in the manifest.

Removing this will allow the activity to reload on rotation change and therefore handle the layout correctly. You will then need to handle the life cycle events of the activity to save and restore transient data during the rotation.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState

Answer (score -1):

Normally the layout file in /res/layout are applied to both portrait and landscape.

For example,

```
/res/layout/activity_main.xml
```

you can add a new folder 
`/res/layout-land`, copy activity_main.xml into this folder and do necessary adjustments

**Make Sure the name of the folder should be layout-land for landscape mode.**

Comment: I did this. What I want to know is, how to use dynamically both layouts without erasing my editText values. The way I did the values didn't change, but I can't change my layouts after activity was called